# Convert multiple header table to long format

Tags: r, excel, flatten

I am reading in an Excel table with multiple rows of headers, which, through read.csv, creates an object like this in **R**.

```
R1 <- c("X", "X.1", "X.2", "X.3", "EU", "EU.1", "EU.2", "US", "US.1", "US.2")
R2 <- c("Min Age", "Max Age", "Min Duration", "Max Duration", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3")
R3 <- c("18", "21", "1", "3", "0.12", "0.32", "0.67", "0.80", "0.90", "1.01")
R4 <- c("22", "25", "1", "3", "0.20", "0.40", "0.70", "0.85", "0.98", "1.05")
R5 <- c("26", "30", "1", "3", "0.25", "0.50", "0.80", "0.90", "1.05", "1.21")
R6 <- c("18", "21", "4", "5", "0.32", "0.60", "0.95", "0.99", "1.30", "1.40")
R7 <- c("22", "25", "4", "5", "0.40", "0.70", "1.07", "1.20", "1.40", "1.50")
R8 <- c("26", "30", "4", "5", "0.55", "0.80", "1.09", "1.34", "1.67", "1.99")
table1 <- as.data.frame(rbind(R1, R2, R3, R4, R5, R6, R7, R8))
```

How do I now 'flatten' this so that I end up with an **R** table with "Min age", "Max Age", "Min Duration", "Max Duration", "Area", "Level", "Price" columns. With the "Area" column showing either "EU" or "US", the "Level" column showing either 1, 2 or 3, and then the "Price" column showing the corresponding price found in the Excel table?

I would use the gather function from tidyr if there weren't multiple header rows, but can't seem to work it with this data, any ideas?

The output should have a total of 36 rows + headers

Comment: When you read the data, you could use `skip` to remove those initial rows

Comment: Thanks, how do I then insert them back in as a column and ensure they're in the correct rows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you skip the first row, as suggested by akrun, you will presumably end up with data that looks something like this: (with "X"s and ".1"/".2" added automatically by R)

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
    ~Min.Age, ~Max.Age, ~Min.Duration, ~Max.Duration,  ~X1.1,  ~X2.1,  ~X3.1, ~X1.2, ~X2.2, ~X3.2,
    "18",     "21",           "1",           "3", "0.12", "0.32", "0.67",  "0.80",  "0.90",  "1.01",
    "22",     "25",           "1",           "3", "0.20", "0.40", "0.70",  "0.85",  "0.98",  "1.05",
    "26",     "30",           "1",           "3", "0.25", "0.50", "0.80",  "0.90",  "1.05",  "1.21",
    "18",     "21",           "4",           "5", "0.32", "0.60", "0.95",  "0.99",  "1.30",  "1.40",
    "22",     "25",           "4",           "5", "0.40", "0.70", "1.07",  "1.20",  "1.40",  "1.50",
    "26",     "30",           "4",           "5", "0.55", "0.80", "1.09",  "1.34",  "1.67",  "1.99"
)
```

With this data, you can then use `gather` to collect all headers beginning with X into one column and price into another. You can `separate` the the headers into the "Level" and "Area". Finally, recode Area and remove "X" from the levels.

```r
df %>% 
    gather(headers, Price, starts_with("X")) %>% 
    separate(headers, c("Level", "Area")) %>% 
    mutate(Area = if_else(Area == "1", "EU", "US"),
           Level = parse_number(Level))
#> # A tibble: 36 x 7
#>    Min.Age Max.Age Min.Duration Max.Duration Level Area  Price
#>    <chr>   <chr>   <chr>        <chr>        <dbl> <chr> <chr>
#>  1 18      21      1            3                1 EU    0.12 
#>  2 22      25      1            3                1 EU    0.20 
#>  3 26      30      1            3                1 EU    0.25 
#>  4 18      21      4            5                1 EU    0.32 
#>  5 22      25      4            5                1 EU    0.40 
#>  6 26      30      4            5                1 EU    0.55 
#>  7 18      21      1            3                2 EU    0.32 
#>  8 22      25      1            3                2 EU    0.40 
#>  9 26      30      1            3                2 EU    0.50 
#> 10 18      21      4            5                2 EU    0.60 
#> # ... with 26 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2018-10-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

P.S. You can find lots of spreadsheet munging workflows here: https://nacnudus.github.io/spreadsheet-munging-strategies/small-multiples-with-all-headers-present-for-each-multiple.html